# Python: normalizing some of the columns of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame from which I want to normalize some arbitrary columns using another arbitrary column:

```py
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

header = tuple(['h_seqNum', 'h_stamp', 'user_id'])
joints = tuple(['head', 'neck', 'torso'])
attribs = tuple(['pos_x','pos_y','pos_z'])

all_columns = it.izip(*it.product(joints, attribs))
multiind_first = list(it.chain(['header']*len(header), all_columns.next(), ['pose',]))
multiind_second = list(it.chain(header, all_columns.next(), ['pose',]))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(65).reshape(5,13),  columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([multiind_first, multiind_second], names=['joint', 'attrib']))
```

The resulting DataFrame is something like this one:

```py
joint    header                            head                       neck                       torso                      pose
attrib   h_seqNum    h_stamp    user_id    pos_x    pos_y    pos_z    pos_x    pos_y    pos_z    pos_x    pos_y    pos_z    pose
0        0.681       0.059      0.607      0.093    0.504    0.975    0.317    0.739    0.129    0.759    0.254    0.814    1
1        0.914       0.420      0.305      0.242    0.700    0.180    0.324    0.171    0.477    0.943    0.877    0.069    0
2        0.522       0.395      0.118      0.739    0.653    0.326    0.947    0.517    0.036    0.647    0.079    0.227    0
3        0.475       0.815      0.792      0.208    0.472    0.427    0.213    0.544    0.440    0.033    0.636    0.527    2
4        0.767       0.774      0.983      0.646    0.949    0.947    0.402    0.015    0.913    0.734    0.192    0.032    0
```

I want to normalize all the columns (attrib) belonging to an arbitrary joint (eg. 'head') using another arbitrary joint (eg. 'torso'). For instance something like.

```py
df['head'] = df['head'] - df['torso']
df['neck'] = df['neck'] - df['torso']
# Note that torso remains "unnormalized"
```

To do so I wrote a function:

```py
def normalize_joints(df, from_joint):
    joint_names = set(joints) - set([from_joint,])
    for j in list(joint_names):
         df[j] = df[j] - df[norm_name]
```

However, when I execute this function I get the following error:

```py
normalize_joints(df, 'torso')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-414-47f39f04716d> in <module>()
----> 1 normalize_joints(df, 'torso')

<ipython-input-407-cf13a67fabd8> in normalize_joints(df, from_joint)
      2     joint_names = set(joints) - set([from_joint,])
      3     for j in list(joint_names):
----> 4         df[j] = df[j] - df[from_joint]

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2117                                          fill_value, limit, takeable=takeable)
   2118 
-> 2119         return frame
   2120 
   2121     def _reindex_index(self, new_index, method, copy, level, fill_value=NA,

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2164     @Appender(_shared_docs['reindex_axis'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)
   2165     def reindex_axis(self, labels, axis=0, method=None, level=None, copy=True,
-> 2166                      limit=None, fill_value=np.nan):
   2167         return super(DataFrame, self).reindex_axis(labels=labels, axis=axis,
   2168                                                    method=method, level=level,

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in _set_item(self, key, value)
    677 
    678     __bool__ = __nonzero__
--> 679 
    680     def bool(self):
    681         """ Return the bool of a single element PandasObject

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in set(self, item, value)
   1768     def sp_index(self):
   1769         return self.values.sp_index
-> 1770 
   1771     @property
   1772     def kind(self):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in _reset_ref_locs(self)
   1054         # see if we can align other
   1055         if hasattr(other, 'reindex_axis'):
-> 1056             if align:
   1057                 axis = getattr(other, '_info_axis_number', 0)
   1058                 other = other.reindex_axis(self.items, axis=axis,

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in _rebuild_ref_locs(self)
   1062 
   1063         # make sure that we can broadcast
-> 1064         is_transposed = False
   1065         if hasattr(other, 'ndim') and hasattr(values, 'ndim'):
   1066             if values.ndim != other.ndim or values.shape == other.shape[::-1]:

AttributeError: _ref_locs
```

After several tries I have not been able to locate the source of my error. If I perform the operation

```py
df['head'] - df['torso']
```

it returns me a DataFrame with the correct result. However, when I try to assign this DataFrame to df['head'] I get the error shown before.

Is it any way to perform this assignment?

Moreover, I was wondering if there are any better ways to perform the same normalization than the one I am trying. Perhaps using groupby and then and applying the normalize function to the selected DataFrame?

**EDIT:**

This error occurred with numpy 1.6 and pandas 0.12

After upgrading to numpy 1.8 and pandas 0.13 the following operation is valid:

```py
df['head'] = df['head'] - df['torso']
```

Comment: In your first code block, you need to replace `multiind_first` with `mi_level_one` and `multiind_second` with `mi_level_two`.

Comment: Replaced. Just an issue of copy-pasting my code. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that I have found a rather simple solution:

```
def normalize(df, from_joint):
    df.drop(['header', 'pose', from_joint], axis=1, level='joint').sub(df[from_joint], level=1)

df.update(normalize(df, 'torso'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your columns are instances of `MultiIndex` try this:

```
def normalize_joints(df, from_joint):
    joint_names = set(joints) - set([from_joint,])
    for j in list(joint_names):
        keys = [(j,c) for c in attribs]
        df[keys] = df[j] - df[from_joint]

print df
normalize_joints(df, 'torso')
print df
```

Output:

```
joint     header                          head                          neck                         torso                          pose
attrib  h_seqNum   h_stamp   user_id     pos_x     pos_y     pos_z     pos_x     pos_y     pos_z     pos_x     pos_y     pos_z      pose
0       0.067366  0.957394  0.983969  0.602662  0.505270  0.990675  0.753841  0.598397  0.846479  0.757155  0.220009  0.328470  0.686525
1       0.806405  0.800388  0.302178  0.935559  0.180360  0.322767  0.230457  0.617555  0.602589  0.109482  0.181803  0.311266  0.929481
2       0.649677  0.237286  0.963088  0.370463  0.471590  0.489256  0.060383  0.070885  0.858312  0.306232  0.511731  0.257015  0.283287
3       0.054800  0.127925  0.099985  0.700160  0.211256  0.026782  0.820380  0.922593  0.600130  0.100745  0.418157  0.869735  0.597275
4       0.678372  0.334520  0.247894  0.616133  0.914610  0.229628  0.317488  0.224910  0.620222  0.952499  0.946568  0.539502  0.838473
joint     header                          head                          neck                         torso                          pose
attrib  h_seqNum   h_stamp   user_id     pos_x     pos_y     pos_z     pos_x     pos_y     pos_z     pos_x     pos_y     pos_z      pose
0       0.067366  0.957394  0.983969 -0.154493  0.285261  0.662205 -0.003314  0.378387  0.518009  0.757155  0.220009  0.328470  0.686525
1       0.806405  0.800388  0.302178  0.826077 -0.001443  0.011501  0.120975  0.435752  0.291322  0.109482  0.181803  0.311266  0.929481
2       0.649677  0.237286  0.963088  0.064231 -0.040141  0.232241 -0.245850 -0.440846  0.601297  0.306232  0.511731  0.257015  0.283287
3       0.054800  0.127925  0.099985  0.599414 -0.206900 -0.842953  0.719635  0.504436 -0.269605  0.100745  0.418157  0.869735  0.597275
4       0.678372  0.334520  0.247894 -0.336366 -0.031958 -0.309874 -0.635011 -0.721658  0.080719  0.952499  0.946568  0.539502  0.838473
```

Comment: Thanks, @xndrme
Your answer has raised me another question. 
Why if df['head'] - df['torso'] produces a pd.DataFrame with the same results as your answer it is not possible to assign it to df['head']?
I understand that it must be something related with the `MultiIndex`, but I do not see why

Comment: The problem is that `df['head']` on a multi-index is just partial, it works for _getting_ the data but it seems that for _setting_ you should provide the entire multilevel indexes (I think it has something to do with the implementation of pandas, maybe some of its developer could answer your question better ;)

Comment: Somehow it seems that the developers had this issue in mind. Upgrading to numpy 1.8 and pandas 0.13 fixed the problem.

Comment: @VGonPa, well, I think I need an upgrade too :)